# Do decorators consume more memory?

Tags: python, memory, decorator

On a Corey Schafer tutorial, he wrote the following code to measure the amount of memory a specific function has consumed.

```
import time
import random
import memory_profiler

names = ['john', 'Corey', 'Adam', 'Steve', 'Rick', 'Thomas']
majors = ['Math', 'Engineering', 'CompSci', 'Art', 'Business']
print('Memory (before): {}Mb'.format(memory_profiler.memory_usage()))

def people_list(num_of_people):
    result = []
    for i in range(num_of_people):
        person = {'id': i, 
                  'name' : random.choice(names),
                  'major' : random.choice(majors)}
        result.append(person)
    return result

t1 = time.process_time()
people_list(1000000)
t2 = time.process_time()
print('Memory (After): {}Mb'.format(memory_profiler.memory_usage()))
print('Took {} seconds'.format(t2-t1))
```

The results were

```
Memory (before): [34.21875]Mb
Memory (After): [34.47265625]Mb
Took 2.390625 seconds
```

but when I tried to create a decorator to add the memory and time measuring functionality to my function, the difference in memory before and after the function execution was huge.
This is my code

```
import time
import random
import memory_profiler

names = ['john', 'Corey', 'Adam', 'Steve', 'Rick', 'Thomas']
majors = ['Math', 'Engineering', 'CompSci', 'Art', 'Business']

def decorator(original_func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        before_memory = memory_profiler.memory_usage()
        print('Memory (before): {} Mbs'.format(before_memory))
        t1 = time.time()
        output = original_func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time()
        time_diff = t2 - t1
        after_memory = memory_profiler.memory_usage()
        print("Memory (after): {} Mbs".format(after_memory))
        print('{} ran in {} seonds'.format(original_func.__name__, time_diff))
        return output
    return wrapper

@decorator
def people_list(num):
    result = []
    for i in range(num):
        person = {'id' : i+1, 
                  'name' : random.choice(names), 
                  'major' : random.choice(majors)}
        result.append(person)
    return result

people_list(1000000)
```

and the results were

```
Memory (before): [47.07421875] Mbs
Memory (after): [319.875] Mbs
people_list ran in 2.5296807289123535 seonds
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without decorator you discard the result of your function call at once. In the decorator example, the result is kept in `output`, when looking at memory usage.

Try the first example with:

```
t1 = time.process_time()
output = people_list(1000000)
t2 = time.process_time()
print('Memory (After): {}Mb'.format(memory_profiler.memory_usage()))
print('Took {} seconds'.format(t2-t1))
```

and you should get the same memory usage.